# chained if-else not working (C++)

Tags: c++, if-statement, chained

I'm a beginner and am having trouble with my chained if-else statement. When I run the program, and I enter which item I select, it always outputs "Invalid entry.". Why isn't it executing the proper function when it is equal to it in the if-statement?

Thank you,

Don

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int sum(int int1, int int2 ){

    return int1 + int2;

}

int difference( int int1, int int2 ){

    return int1 - int2;

}

int product( int int1, int int2 ){

    return int1 * int2;

}

int quotient( int int1, int int2 ){

    return int1 / int2;

}

int main(){

cout << "\nWelcome to the calculator.\n\n";
cout << "Please enter two numbers.\n\n";

int a;
int b;
cin >> a >> b;

cout << "What would you like to do with these numbers?\nHere are your options: add, subtract, multiply, or divide.\n\n";

string add;
string subtract;
string multiply;
string divide;

string choice;
cin >> choice;


if( choice == add )
    cout << sum( a, b );
else if ( choice == subtract )
    cout << difference( a, b );
else if ( choice == multiply )
    cout << product( a, b );
else if ( choice == divide )
    cout << quotient( a, b );
else 
    cout << "Invalid entry.\n"; 

return 0;

}
```

Comment: You probably should add a language tag

Comment: Thanks for the tip, this is my first post.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

With this statement:

```
string add;
```

You are creating a string variable with the name `add`, but there is not yet a value assigned to it. So when you compare the variable with the user input, the program will see `add` as the value `null` and that is not equal to whatever the user inputs.

You want to assign a value to it:

```
string add = "add";
```

And all other strings the same.

And to compare std::string:

```
if(choice == add)
```

Another way to do it, is just to check it directly with a constant string:

```
if(choice == "add"){
  //do something
}else if(choice == "subtract") 
  //do something else
```

Comment: calculator.cpp:48:11: error: no member named 'equals' in
      'std::__1::basic_string<char>' I am using textedit on mac. Is that a problem?

Comment: The `strcmp` function does not work with `std::string`.  The `std::string` class uses `operator==()`.  Downvoting.